# ubuntu on steam help!

Tags: steam

Hi i am very new to ubuntu but am getting the hang of it. I need steam for my gaming needs but whenever i type (sudo apt-get install steam -y) it says something like this: package (steam) you have selected no canadate.
And then i try one other method: i have downloaded steam on my computer but have not installed it yet so i can't open the steam program but once i click the valve icon, enter my password and start installing after the white dots in the terminal are all the way to the other side it says: you are missing the following 32bit libraries and steam may not run:libc.so.6. i would appreciate any help and also knowing where to get a  libc.so.6 folder. thanks ahead of time!:)

Comment: One command: sudo apt-get install libc6

Comment: so i did as u said and it told me to type (yes do as i say ) after that so i did and pressed enter then it spammed (do as i say) like crazy! is that normal?

Comment: ....and should i let it stay like that for a while? again thanks so much!

Comment: No it's not typing sudo apt-get install libc6 -y shouldn't do that :/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get steam on the system is to download the .deb file from the valve developer community. You can get the download [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux#Ubuntu).

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use software center, and search for stream and install it from the software center, and it probably work best this way, or else you need to install wine1.7, and open the downloaded exe file whit wine loader, and to install wine you have to enter this in the terminal:

```
       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine-ubuntu/ppa
       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: hey Michael, so i searched the software center and there were no results for steam but there was a steam launcher, i installed it and it did absolutely nothing (Or i do not know how to use it.)and i tried your commands and my terminal kept on saying error. Any other way?

Comment: And i also tried in the terminal: (sudo apt-get install steam)it said: package (steam) has no installation candidate